# What's the difference between 同样 and 一样

Tags: word-choice, difference

I'm so confused about this two phrases, I think they can be used interchangeably in most circumstances, but here's the examples:

他们两个长得一样。
Why can't we say 他们两个长得同样?

妈妈点了一杯咖啡，我也一样。
Why can't we say 妈妈点了一杯咖啡，我也同样?

他认识我，同样，我也认识他。
Why can't we say 他认识我，一样，我也认识他?

I feel like my head is going to explode! Could you please give me some detailed explanation? I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: cf。"一样"和"同样"有什么区别? http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/13552260.html

Comment: Well, we can't have exploding heads, can we? Makes an awful mess! I don't know the answer, but if you reverse engineer and say 'Those 2 look the same.' or 'Those 2 look equal.', which do you prefer in English? I think that is something like your problem in Chinese. Don't just think they are both the same 'same' with no nuances of difference.

Comment: Related: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/4900/difference-between-%E5%90%8C%E4%B8%80-and-%E4%B8%80%E6%A0%B7

Answer (score 7):

問得好!

Here are some differences.

syntactic difference:

- 一樣 can be a predicate (謂語).
- 同樣 is only used as a modifier 修飾語, i.e. in front of a noun and connected with 的 (adjectival) , or in front of a verb phrase, or sentence (adverbial).

semantic difference:

- 一樣 same (identical)
- 同樣 same (equivalent)

I think these will account for your examples:

- 他们两个长得同样:  V得 here requires a predicate, so 同样 is bad.
- 妈妈点了一杯咖啡，我也一样: here 一样 is [pro-verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-verb) (not proverb) which resumes the predicate 点了一杯咖啡; 同样 can't do that.
- 他认识我，同样，我也认识他: here 同样 is an adverbial; it means 'in the same way'

Another example, that (I think) shows the semantic difference:

- 我在美國看到同樣的情形: I saw the same (equivalent) situation in America.

I'm a little less sure on this one, but I don't think it has to be an exactly identical situation; just one that strikes me as fundamentally equivalent.

Anyway, nice examples, and good careful thinking!

Comment: regarding ３：at the start of a phrase 同样 is needed  (putting adverb at at the start),
it seems very hard to find clauses starting with 一样

Comment: Excellent explanation from the perspective of a native Chinese speaker.